# How to execute a callback who's type is a generic type constrained with multiple return types?

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to allow a callback parameter in my function that permits multiple return tuples. To achieve this, I'm using generics to define the parameter type for the callback.

```golang
func Get[
    In any,
    Out any,
    TranslateFn func(In) Out | func(In) (Out, error),
](
    input In,
    translate TranslateFn,
) (*Out, error) {
    // Call translate to convert the input to the output.
    // If translate is an erroring function, make sure the error is
    // forwarded to the response of this function.
}
```

Since TranslateFn is constrained to either of those two return types (either `Out` or `(Out, error)`), I assumed I would be able to call it.

What I'd like to do is something like the following, however I cannot because I'm unable to use type assertion on the `translate` argument.

> invalid operation: cannot use type assertion on type parameter value translate (variable of type TranslateFn constrained by func(In) Out|func(In) (Out, error))

```golang
func Get[
    In any,
    Out any,
    TranslateFn func(In) Out | func(In) (Out, error),
](
    input In,
    translate TranslateFn,
) (*Out, error) {
    if erroringFn, isErroringTranslateFn := translate.(func(In) (Out, error)); isErroringTranslateFn {
        out, err := erroringFn(input)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return &out, nil
    }

    if nonErroringFn, isNonErroringTranslateFn := translate.(func(In) Out); isNonErroringTranslateFn {
        out, err := nonErroringFn(input)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return &out, nil
    }

    panic("translate function must be either func(In) (Out, error) or func(In) Out")
}
```

Without type assertion, how would I go about invoking this callback, or determining which of the generic variations was provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it into an interface first and then do type assertion (or type switch). E.g. `any(v).(T)`

```golang
func Get[
    In any,
    Out any,
    TranslateFn func(In) Out | func(In) (Out, error),
](
    input In,
    translate TranslateFn,
) (*Out, error) {
    switch f := any(translate).(type) {
    case func(In) (Out, error):
        out, err := f(input)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return &out, nil
    case func(In) Out:
        out := f(input)
        return &out, nil
    }

    panic("shouldn't happen")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As mkopriva's answer suggests, a type switch is an option, but generally speaking, I would advise against allowing both types of, what is essentially, callbacks. Instead I'd just do something like this:

```
func Get[
    In any,
    Out any,
    TranslateFn func(In) (Out, error),
](
    input In,
    translate TranslateFn,
) (*Out, error) {
    o, err := translate(in)
    if err != nil {
         return nil, err
    }
    return &o, nil
}
```

Now, if you have a bunch of functions you want to use, but a significant proportion of them don't return an error, you can provide a convenience wrapper function:

```
func ErrWrap[In any, Out any] (cb func(In) Out) func (In) (Out, error) {
    return func (i In) (Out, error) {
        o := cb(i)
        return o, nil
    }
}
```

With this, all functions that don't return an error can be neatly wrapped to return an error value (which will simply always be `nil`).

The benefit is that it simplifies your current `Get` function, so it's just a lot cleaner, and easier to read/maintain for others (and yourself). Going forwards, it communicates quite clearly that `Get` expects a callback that returns a value of type `Out`, and an error, but existing functions (and places they are called) needn't be immediately refactored to account for a second return value, although you should know that all calls to `ErrWrap` are indicators of technical debt.